# A question about simple connected graph such that all degrees are at least $2$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be A simple connected graph such that all degrees are at least $2$. Is it true that every vertex is on a circle ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. A counter example would be two disjoint cycles plus one connecting edge. The connecting edge is not part of any cycle.

Edit: To get a vertex that is not on a cylce one can modify the example above by putting an extra vertex in the middle of the connecting edge.

Comment: but i meant vertices, not edges

Comment: still, in a circle we can visit a vertex twice, so your example does not contradicts the assertion.